# How to send notification with FCM XMPP

Tags: notifications, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

i need to send notification using fcm in android with xmpp. i tried to lot but not found any examples. Can anyone help me to finish this. i need to send a notification to particular device id using fcm without firebase. i need example

Comment: Maybe some code that you have tried would help. Also why do you need to use XMPP? Note that that is only necessary if you want delivery acknowledgement, HTTP is much easier to implement so depends on the need for acknowledgement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorials for me it helps me a loot
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiKCEa5_Cs8